Unable to create EKS Cluster with Terraform [ Instances failed to join the Kubernetes cluster ]
Terraform code below
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_eks_cluster" "example" {
  name     = "example-cluster"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.example.arn

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = aws_subnet.example[*].id
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name = "example-role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "eks.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "example-AmazonEKSClusterPolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.example.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "example-AmazonEKSServicePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.example.name
}

resource "aws_vpc" "example" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  count = 2
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.example.id
  cidr_block = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.example.cidr_block, 8, count.index)
  availability_zone = element(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, count.index)
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "example" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.example.name
  node_group_name = "example-node-group"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.example_node_group.arn
  subnet_ids      = aws_subnet.example[*].id

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 2
    max_size     = 3
    min_size     = 1
  }

  instance_types = ["t3.medium"]

  remote_access {
    ec2_ssh_key = "my-key"
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "example-node-group"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "example_node_group" {
  name = "example-node-group-role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "example-AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.example_node_group.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "example-AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
  role       = aws_iam_role.example_node_group.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "example-AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.example_node_group.name
}

I have created key-pair as below
aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name my-key --query 'KeyMaterial' --output text > my-key.pem --region us-west-2 
ls -l my-key.pem 
chmod 600 my-key.pem

However, when I run terraform I get error like below
_eks_node_group.example: Still creating... [22m40s elapsed]
aws_eks_node_group.example: Still creating... [22m50s elapsed]
aws_eks_node_group.example: Still creating... [23m0s elapsed]
aws_eks_node_group.example: Still creating... [23m10s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: waiting for EKS Node Group (example-cluster:example-node-group) create: unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED', wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last error: i-008194c5266bcbf08, i-0df3c0087882195a7: NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster
│ 
│   with aws_eks_node_group.example,
│   on main.tf line 86, in resource "aws_eks_node_group" "example":
│   86: resource "aws_eks_node_group" "example" {
│ 
╵

Please assist.

I'm not sure if this is the code in it's entirety, but it could be your networking configuration is off.

Make sure that the cluster role is properly configured before the cluster is created, so that aws_eks_cluster depends on the aws_iam_role_policy_attachment resources.
